# How to have up to date software and more open source software in the Software Centre?

Tags: package-management, software-center, software-sources

I would like to have a better selection of free software in the Software Centre and have newer versions of the packages. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 4):

You can search in Personal Package Archives (PPA) the package you want to have up to date.

[Personal Package Archives for Ubuntu](https://edge.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+ppas)

just enter the program to search and it will show all associated ppa with this program. (exam. banshee)

There are three steps to what you must be to run:

1. `add-apt-repository`: adds a PPA to your list of sources, so that Ubuntu knows to look for updates from that PPA as well as from the official Ubuntu sources. Usually this is used to allow developers to provide updates more quickly than those in the official Ubuntu repositories.
2. `apt-get update` tells apt-get to update its database of what packages can be installed and where to install them from.
3. `apt-get install` causes apt-get to find the package in its database and download and install the indicated file.
4. `sudo ppa-purge ppa:` deletes a PPA to your list of sources.

   - [What are PPAs and how do I use them?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4983/what-are-ppas-and-how-do-i-use-them)

Now you can have Up to date software and view it in software center.